# Special case for Group By counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im asked to report the number of charges a provider has for the current month. The current criteria is one code means one charge. The problem I have right now is they added an exception for one of the providers; wherein if the codes that start with F or end with G and there are 4 or 5 of them for one patient on the same day of service, they only count as 3 charges.

```
For example (Pv2 is the one with the special case)
Prov       Patient       ServiceDate       Code
Pv1          Pt1           1/1/2019        99001
Pv1          Pt2           1/4/2019        99004
Pv1          Pt2           1/2/2019        F0001
Pv2          Pt1           1/1/2019        F0001
PV2          Pt1           1/1/2019        1000G
PV2          Pt1           1/1/2019        F0012
PV2          Pt1           1/1/2019        1003G
PV2          Pt1           1/1/2019        F1100
PV2          Pt2           1/4/2019        99001
```

The report should look like this

```
Prov         ChargeCount
Pv1            3
Pv2            4
```

This is my current code:

```
Select Prov, Count(Code)
From Table
Group by Prov
```

So mine outputs

```
Prov         ChargeCount
Pv1            3
Pv2            6
```

Comment: Clarify your logic. If there is at least 1 code that starts with an F or ends with G, mark that as 3 charges?

Comment: Only if there are 4/5 of those F & G codes for 1 patient on the same day. Otherwise all codes count as 1 charge.

Comment: So it has to specifically be 4 OR 5 codes that start with F or end with G for the same patient on that day? What about 6 codes?

Comment: We have not seen 6 codes or more for same patient on same day so I would have to discuss that with my supervisor but right now we only discussed 4/5, maybe for the 6 or more make it like normal and make it 1 code = 1 charge as it wasnt stated by my supervisor yet.

Comment: And what if there are 4 or 5 with F or G and 2 additional without F or G? The SUM will be 5?

Comment: I would suggest getting much more information from your supervisor about every use case then coming back here and editing your question. There are a lot of loose ends about the question currently like the others have stated.

Comment: We havent seen more than 5 codes for same patient on same day but if your case happens then yes it will count as 5 @mrRabbani

Answer (score 0):

This is functional code that will do what you need, and is the first approach I would take. Basically, you total your exceptions and your standard cases separately, then apply your exception adjustments and add the two values together.

```
With DataGather as (
    SELECT
        Prov,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Code Like 'F%' Or Code Like '%G' 
                    Then 1
                Else 0
            END
        ) as FGCodes,
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN WHEN Code Like 'F%' Or Code Like '%G' 
                    Then 0
                Else 1
            END
        ) as Codes
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Prov
    )
SELECT Prov,
    Codes + 
        CASE
            WHEN FGCodes > 3
                THEN 3
            ELSE FGCodes
        END as ChargeCount
FROM DataGather
```

Edit:

With your additional condition, the last CASE statement can be rewritten as:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN FGCodes <= 3
            THEN FGCodes
        WHEN FGCodes <= 5
            THEN 3
        ELSE 5
    END as ChargeCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this below CTE code-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Prov,Patient, 3 CNT
    FROM your_table
    WHERE YEAR(ServiceDate)  = 2019
    AND MONTH(ServiceDate) = 1
    AND (
        LEFT(Code,1) = 'F' OR RIGHT(Code,1)  = 'G'
    )
    GROUP BY Prov,Patient
    HAVING COUNT(Code) IN (4,5)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Prov,Patient, COUNT(Code) 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE YEAR(ServiceDate)  = 2019
    AND MONTH(ServiceDate) = 1
    AND (
        LEFT(Code,1) = 'F' OR RIGHT(Code,1)  = 'G'
    )
    GROUP BY Prov,Patient
    HAVING COUNT(Code) NOT IN (4,5)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Prov,Patient, COUNT(Code) 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE YEAR(ServiceDate)  = 2019
    AND MONTH(ServiceDate) = 1
    AND LEFT(Code,1) <> 'F' 
    AND RIGHT(Code,1)  <> 'G'
    GROUP BY Prov,Patient
)

SELECT Prov, SUM(CNT) ChargeCount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Prov
```

Output is-

```
Prov    ChargeCount
Pv1     3
PV2     4
```